# Matlab, Cross Product Multi Dim matrix

Tags: matlab, cross-product

I have u1 v1 w1(velocity components) volumetric data. Size of u1 is NxNxN (N is 100) and same is true frol v1 and w1.

I have one more case of u2, v2, w2, each one of size NxNxN. both these data sets are obtained from TriScatteredInterp and meshgrid. Basically i plotted streamlines for these two cases and now i want to see how much deviation is there between these streamlines (from case 1 to 2.). I need to find the angle between them at the points given by meshgrid. But cross product wont work (A and B must have at least one dimension of length 3.).. any suggestion ?? Thanks a lot

Comment: `acos` of the scalar product? As in `acos(u1.*u2+v1.*v2+w1.*w2)./sqrt((u1.^2+v1.^2+w1.^2).*(u2.^2+v2.^2+w2.^2))` or something.

Comment: Thanks Andras... I shall give it a try ... many thanks

Comment: Note that you could compute the cross product manually the same way. The cross product of `(x1,y1,z1)` with `(x2,y2,z2)` is simply `(y1*z2-z1*y2,z1*x2-x1*z2,x1*y2-y1*x2)`, give or take a few signs.

Comment: Hello Andras, thanks for your suggestion. With the help of one fellow Matlab user, i was able to get the angles using atan2 which takes care of the quadrant in which the angle lies and hence the sign. Many thanks ,, cheers

Comment: No problem. If you feel that your question and solution can help future readers, please self-answer your question. Otherwise, please consider deleting this question.

Answer (score 1):

the angle can be found using

```
angle = atan2(norm(cross(a,b)),dot(a,b))
```

[using Four-quadrant inverse tangent]; but for my case the cross product part will not work as the size of each velocity component in 100x100x100.

Using Concatenate function of Matlab, the three components of Velocity1 and Velocity2 can be combined to result in a matrix having size NxNxNx3. Now for each triplet/combination of V1(u1,v1, w1) and V2(u2,v2, w2), cross product(call it C) can be taken in 4th dimension which results in Matrix having size NxNxNx3. In the above mentioned formula, to have the magnitude/norm of the result of cross product, we have to take dot product of C with C itself in 4th dimension and square root it to get the magnitude and to make its size again to NxNxN. so finally it can be done like--

```
   A = cat(4,u1,v1,w1); % Combine the three components in the 4th dimension
   B = cat(4,u2,v2,w2); % Ditto
   C = cross(A,B,4); % Take the cross products there.
   ang = atan2(sqrt(dot(C,C,4)),dot(A,B,4));
```

This solution is given by Mr Roger Stafford(Matlab website) and all credit goes to him.

answer can be found here.. 
http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/281635-cross-product-multi-dim-data

Comment: When I meant "self-answer", I meant giving a proper, full answer according to the standards of Stack Overflow:) Answers that contain only links are of very low quality, and have a high chance of getting deleted. Please add all relevant information to your answer, so that the question and answer as they are here are instructive and useful.

Comment: Ok I will do it . My apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: Don't worry about it, what matters is that you're here to contribute and that you're willing to do it right:) Thank you. Welcome to Stack Overflow!